# Mysql Match…against query performance in InnoDB Mysql 5.6

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to search records in the table which contains millions of records. I have recently updated Mysql version from 5.1 to 5.6.

I was using `like` in query which was taking around 15 sec to 30 sec.

Currently I have modified query to use `MATCH... AGAINST` feature of mysql 5.6 INNODB. My query goes like this.

```
SELECT  JOB.IDJOB, JOB.IDEMPLOYER .....
    FROM  JOB
    WHERE  ( ( JOB.ITJOBSTARTTYPE=2  AND  JOB.DTPLANNEDEND >= '2015-07-06' )
         OR  ( JOB.ITJOBSTARTTYPE=1
                AND  ( ( JOB.ITJOBENDTYPE=2 ) OR  ( JOB.DTJOBEND>='2015-07-06') ) 
             )
         OR  ( JOB.ITJOBSTARTTYPE=3
                AND  ( (JOB.DTJOBEND >='2015-07-06')  OR  (JOB.ITJOBENDTYPE=2) ) 
             ) 
           )
      AND  MATCH(VCJOBTITLE, LVJOBCOMPANYDESCRIPTION, VCCOMPANYNAME,
                VCSALARYDESC, VCCITY, VCQUALIFICATIONREQUIRED,VCJOBREFERENCE,
                LVJOBKEYWORDS )
           AGAINST ('test' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
    ORDER BY  JOB.ITJOBBAND ASC,
              JOB.VCRANKING DESC,
              JOB.IDJOB DESC,
              JOB.FJOBWEIGHT ASC
    LIMIT  50;
```

Which takes 80- 120 seconds (3X slower )

If I remove `ORDER BY` it will load in 6 to 10 sec.

Is their any setting Or performance tunning we can apply here?

Edit: using `show create table JOB;`

```
 CREATE TABLE `JOB` (
  `idJob` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idEmployer` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcJobTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lvJobCompanyDescription` text,
  `idBasket` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtActualgolive` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'whenever job status become online',
  `boImmediatelygolive` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtRequestedgolive` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtActualend` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'when job is set to be archieved',
  `dtPlannedend` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'when posting a job this is calculated. batch will look at this date. date on which regular jobs will be archievd, or date on which internship jobs will be changed to listing',
  `dtRequestedend` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'exact date on which employer wants jobs to be archieved',
  `dtApplicationdeadline` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'job will be converted to listing on this date',
  `boDurationinweeks` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'whether employer gave duration in weeks or not',
  `itDurationweeks` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boIsoncredit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtCreditend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fJobbaseprice` float NOT NULL,
  `fJobpriceafteradminitemdiscount` float NOT NULL COMMENT 'price after admin item discount',
  `fJobpriceafterpromodiscount` float NOT NULL COMMENT 'price after promo discount',
  `vcPromotioncode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcCompanyname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `vcSalarydesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vcCity` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `vcCounty` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcQualificationrequired` text,
  `boWorkfromhome` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boResidential` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boIndoor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boOutdoor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boIndoorandoutdoor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itJobstarttype` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date,immidiate,always recruiting',
  `dtJobstart` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `itJobendtype` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date,ongoing',
  `dtJobend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtFeaturedstart` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtFeaturedend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `itFulltimeparttime` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'fulltime,parttime,both',
  `boEveningtime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boDaytime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boWeekend` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boNewsletter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vcApplyemail` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcApplyphone` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcApplyaddress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcApplyURL` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boRequirephone` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boRequireaddress` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boRequirecv` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boFeatured` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blLogo` longblob,
  `itJobstatus` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'online,offline',
  `itEmailedtofriendcount` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'keeps count of how many times users clicked on link email this to friend',
  `itDeadlinetype` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idInternshiptypemaster` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcLengthofscheme` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtInternshiplistingend` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date when internship job will archieve',
  `itJobband` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boGraduate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boInternship` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boGaptemp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boParttimeholiday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boEntrylevel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `boHundredPercentDiscountApplicable` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vcContactdetails` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcJobreference` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'for importing totaljobs feeds',
  `vcJoburlparam` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'for importing totaljobs url params',
  `dtPutInCurrentBand` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date when job is online and put in band 3',
  `itInitcountycount` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lvJobkeywords` text,
  `fJobweight` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '1.00' COMMENT 'Holds the job weight ranging between 0 to 1 (1 being the highest weight)',
  `dtReinstatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `boIncludeiniframe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boIsAdvertFeatured` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itincludexml` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `boAddtojobalert` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `vcRanking` int(11) DEFAULT '999999',
  `itIncludeUkptj` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idJob`),
  KEY `JOB_I_1` (`idEmployer`,`itJobstatus`),
  KEY `JOB_I_2` (`itJobstatus`,`boGaptemp`,`dtJobstart`),
  KEY `JOB_I_3` (`itJobstatus`,`boGraduate`,`dtJobstart`),
  KEY `JOB_I_4` (`itJobstatus`,`boInternship`,`dtJobstart`),
  KEY `JOB_I_5` (`itJobstatus`,`boParttimeholiday`,`dtJobstart`),
  KEY `FI_JOB_idOrder_ORDER_idOrder` (`idBasket`),
  KEY `FI_JOB_vcPromotioncode_PROMOTION_vcPromotioncode` (`vcPromotioncode`),
  KEY `FI_JOB_idInternshiptype_ITTM_idInternshiptypemaster` (`idInternshiptypemaster`),
  KEY `JOB_I_6` (`created_at`),
  KEY `boEntrylevel` (`boEntrylevel`),
  KEY `itJobband` (`itJobband`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `index_ft_search` (`vcJobTitle`,`lvJobCompanyDescription`,`vcCompanyname`,`vcSalarydesc`,`vcCity`,`vcQualificationrequired`,`vcJobreference`,`lvJobkeywords`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_idEmployer_EMPLOYER_idEmployer` FOREIGN KEY (`idEmployer`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYER` (`idEmployer`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_idInternshiptype_ITTM_idInternshiptypemaster` FOREIGN KEY (`idInternshiptypemaster`) REFERENCES `INTERNSHIPTYPEMASTER` (`idInternshiptypemaster`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_idOrder_ORDER_idOrder` FOREIGN KEY (`idBasket`) REFERENCES `BASKET` (`idBasket`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_vcPromotioncode_PROMOTION_vcPromotioncode` FOREIGN KEY (`vcPromotioncode`) REFERENCES `PROMOTION` (`vcPromotioncode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1739324 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Edit:

Without sort:

[image]

With Sort:

[image]

Comment: can you elaborate on which all indexes are there on table??

Comment: I have edited question to show table structure

Comment: Please provide the `EXPLAIN` for the various cases.  Suggest using `EXPLAIN SELECT ... \G` in the mysql commandline tool -- this may avoid wide text.

Comment: Without the `ORDER BY`, the query will return the first 50 rows it finds.  With the `ORDER BY` it has to find the possible rows, sort them, then delivery 50.  So, the sort is slower for multiple reasons.

Comment: How many rows are returned with just the FT test?  (Remove the rest of the WHERE, and the limit, and count the rows)

Comment: Which [place](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?22,632800,632800) do you want to discuss this.

Comment: Only full text search returns 368044 records